# Is ternary operator possible here?

Tags: php

I'm trying to set `$value1`, `$value2`, `$value3` entirely using ternary operators. This is what it looks like without ternary operators:

```
if ($chk1 == 20) {
   $value1 = true;                       
   if ($chk2 == 40) {
      $value2  = 100 ;
      $value3 = 300;
   } else {
      $value2 = 200 ;
      $value3 = 400;
   }
} else {
   $value1 = false;
}
```

I can set `$value2` and `$value3`, but not sure how to set `$value1`. Can it be done?

```
if ($chk1 == 20) {
   $value1 = true;                       
   $value2 = ($chk2 == 40) ? 100 : 200;
   $value3 = ($chk2 == 40) ? 300 : 400;
} else {
   $value1 = false;
}
```

Comment: This is a bad question and you should feel bad for asking it.

Comment: @Ignacio, That's quite a strange comment, so I'm just going to ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I'll explain then.

The behavior for `$value1` is well-defined. If `$chk1` equals 20 then it's `true`, otherwise it's `false`.

The behavior for `$value2` and `$value3` however is not quite as simple. If `$chk1` is 20 then they are given values based on `$chk2`. However, if `$chk1` is *not* 20 then they are **undefined**. The ternary operator has no concept of "undefined"; it only understands "true" and "false". Therefore, this entire system **cannot** be replaced by only a series of ternary operations, and the if statement checking the value of `$chk1` *must* exist.

And this doesn't even touch upon the issues that exist if `$chk2` was actually a function call with side effects.

Comment: He has already taken care of that in his post.  `$value2` and `$value3` aren't touched at all if `$chk1` doesn't equal 20.

Comment: Is it not possible to use ring0's answer except default $value2 and $value3 to NULL to account for undefined?

Comment: @samquo: It is possible to use houbysoft's answer, provided that NULL is actually a useful value for them to be, rather than having them remain undefined.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it using ternary operators:

```
$value1 = ($chk1 == 20) ? true : false;
```

However, that's unnecessary here, you could just do:

```
$value1 = ($chk1 == 20);
```

Also, if you'd drop the `if ($chk1 == 20)` and you want `$value2` and `$value3` to be set only if `$chk1 == 20`, you'd need to change them as well, as otherwise they would be set even if `$chk1 != 20` which is different from the initial code you posted.

For example, you could do:

```
$value2 = ($chk1 == 20) ? (($chk2 == 40) ? 100 : 200) : $value2;
$value3 = ($chk1 == 20) ? (($chk2 == 40) ? 300 : 400) : $value3;
```

Which should work (don't have where to test PHP right now), leaving value2 and value3 unchanged if `$chk1 == 20`.

However, I'd leave it at the `ifs` for readability, since this kind of ternary operator usage is, well, uncommon to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

The *ternary* operator syntax is

```
  <condition> ? <returned-value-if-true> : <returned-value-if-false>
```

for instance

```
  $value = $a < $b ? 10 : 20;
```

$value takes 10 if ($a < $b), otherwise it receives 20.

In your case

```
  $value1 = ($chk1 == 20 ? true : false);
```

using the *ternary* operator.

**edit** the whole program. Provided that `$value2/3` do not get assigned if $chk1 != 20
Using only the ternary operator

```
  $value1 = ($chk1 == 20 ? true : false);
  $value2 = ($chk1 == 20 ? ($chk2 == 40 ? 100 : 200) : $value2);
  $value3 = ($chk1 == 20 ? ($chk2 == 40 ? 300 : 400) : $value3);
```

Comment: I made an edit - emphasizing the fact that $value2 and $value3 do not get assigned if $chk1 != 20.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to reduce the readability of the code, then do this:

```
if ($value1 = ($chk1 == 20)) {     
   $value2 = ($chk2 == 40) ? 100 : 200;
   $value3 = ($chk2 == 40) ? 300 : 400;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing?

```
$value1=($chk1==20);
```

No need for ternary.  Just take the boolean value out of `($chk1==20)`.

If you wanted to use ternary, you could as well, just as you did with the other values, but it would be pointless.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not handle `$value2` and `$value3`.

Comment: @Ignacio, he already handled $value2 and $value3, that wasn't his question.

Comment: Except that they're *also* dependent on `$chk1`.

Comment: @Ignacio, I don't see how it matters.

Comment: @Brad, Ignacio is right. That's the whole idea behind my question.

Comment: @sillow, Why would you want to use ternary when you don't need it?  If you did want to use it, it's quite simple.  `$value1=($chk1==20)?true:false`